# Proper practice for setup upon load in R package development

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, glog

What is the correct way to go about automatically running some setup code (either in R or C++) once per package loading?  Ideally, said code would execute once the user did `library(mypackage)`.  Right now, it's contained in a `setup()` function that needs to be run once before anything else.

Just for more context, in my specific case, I'm using an external library that uses [glog](https://github.com/google/glog) and I need to execute `google::InitGoogleLogging()` once and only once.  It's slightly awkward because I'm trying to use it [within a library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-glog/issues/113) because I have to, even though it's supposed to be called from a `main`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just read 'Writing R Extensions' and follow the leads -- it is either `.onAttach()` or `.onLoad()`.  I have lots of packages that do little things there -- and it doesn't matter this calls to C++ (via Rcpp or not) as you are simply asking about where to initialise things.

**Example:** [Rblpapi creates a connection and stores it](https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi/blob/master/R/init.R#L21-L35)

```
.pkgenv <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())

.onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    if (getOption("blpAutoConnect", FALSE)) {
        con <- blpConnect()
        if (getOption("blpVerbose", FALSE)) {
            packageStartupMessage(paste0("Created and stored default connection object ",
                                         "for Rblpapi version ",
                                         packageDescription("Rblpapi")$Version, "."))
        }
    } else {
        con <- NULL
    }
    assign("con", con, envir=.pkgenv)
}
```

I had some (not public) code that set up a handle (using C++ code) to a proprietary database the same way.  The key is that these hooks *guarantee you* execution on package load / attach which is what you want here.

Comment: Thanks.  I was searching for "setup" in "Writing R Extensions", which didn't turn up anything.

Comment: I hear you. These things are too scattered around -- but that was part of the reason we created the r-package-devel mailing list.  Topics like this do get discussed there, and it has a good signal/noise ratio.   SO works too at times :)